# Laplace transform of the derivative of the dirac delta function times another function

Tags: derivatives, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

I'm trying to solve a DE involving terms of the form $\dot{\delta}(t-k)f(t)$ and $\ddot{\delta}(t-k)f(t)$, where $k>0$. I would therefore like to find the Laplace transform of these terms. My approach so far has been to simply integrate by parts, ie in the case of $\dot{\delta}(t-k)f(t)$ I get

$\mathcal{L}\left\{ \dot{\delta}\left(t-k\right)f\left(t\right)\right\} =\int_{0}^{\infty}\dot{\delta}\left(t-k\right)f\left(t\right)\exp\left(-ts\right)dt$

$=\left[\delta\left(t-k\right)f\left(t\right)\exp\left(-ts\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\delta\left(t-k\right)\left[\dot{f}\left(t\right)\exp\left(-ts\right)-sf\left(t\right)\exp\left(-ts\right)\right]dt$

Since $\delta\left(t\right)=0$ for all $t\neq k$ and since $k>0$, it must hold that $\left[\delta\left(t-k\right)f\left(t\right)\exp\left(-ts\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty}=0$, so by the sifting property of $\delta(t)$ I get

$\mathcal{L}\left\{ \dot{\delta}\left(t-k\right)f\left(t\right)\right\} = \left(sf\left(k\right)-\dot{f}\left(k\right)\right)\exp\left(-ks\right)$

Using the same approach, I get

$\mathcal{L}\left\{ \ddot{\delta}\left(t-k\right)f\left(t\right)\right\} =\left(\ddot{f}\left(k\right)-2s\dot{f}\left(k\right)+s^{2}f\left(k\right)\right)\exp\left(-ks\right)$

My question has two parts:

1) Is this the correct approach?

2) What happens if $k=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach is correct ***in a heuristic sense***.  But the symbol $\int_0^\infty \delta^{(n)}\phi(t)\,dt$ is ***not*** and integral.

The [Distributional Derivative of the Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Distributional_derivatives) is defined such that for every suitable test function $\phi$, we have

$$\langle \delta_a',\phi \rangle =(-1)\phi'(a)\tag 1$$

The $n$'the derivative is similarly defined by

$$\langle \delta_a^{(n)},\phi \rangle =(-1)^n\phi^{(n)}(a)\tag 2$$

---

> Note that both $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be ***heuristically*** derived by formally applying integration by parts, proceeding as if the Dirac Delta was an ordinary function rather than a generalized function.

---

Therefore, if $\phi(t) =f(t)e^{-st}$ in $(1)$, then

$$\int_0^\infty \delta'(t-k)f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=-\left.\frac{d(f(t)e^{-st})}{dt}\right|_{t=k}=(-f'(k)+sf(k))e^{-sk}$$

And if $\phi(t) =f(t)e^{-st}$ in $(2)$ with $n=2$, then

$$\int_0^\infty \delta''(t-k)f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=\left.\frac{d^2(f(t)e^{-st})}{dt^2}\right|_{t=k}=(f''(k)-2sf'(k)+s^2f(k))e^{-sk}$$

Comment: Another variant explanation as to why seeming heuristics involving integrals of generalized functions give correct answers, is that the apparent integrals are not literal, numerical integrals, but, rather, are extensions-by-continuity of maps given by literal integrals on nicer functions... but/and inheriting the same good properties of literal integrals (which is why the manipulations give correct outcomes).

Comment: @paulgarrett Indeed!  Excellent comment (+1)!

Comment: Thanks! :) (After all, there's surely some reason why Heaviside... then Dirac, Bethe, et al got the right answers so often!)

Comment: @paulgarrett Dirac was a pure genius!  Bethe and Heaviside were pretty smart themselves.  I feel humbled to know that there are/were minds that were so vast.

Comment: While we're here, it was just a few years ago that I looked directly at some of Dirac's stuff (rather than just listening to rumors) and (before 1930, I think) he clearly had the idea of "Gelfand triples/Sobolev spaces" $H^1\subset L^2\subset H^{-1}$, with "integrate over light-cone" as a distribution inside $H^{-1}$, the fact the solving (elliptic) differential equations "improves" the Sobolev index, and such stuff. Really amazing intuition/inspiration.

Comment: By (2) I would assume that the results will hold even when $k=0$. Is this true? If so, does it have something to do with the fact that the Laplace transform can be written as $\mathcal{L}{f}(s) = \int_{0^-}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt$?

Comment: Yes.  Note that $\int_{0^-}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)u(x)\,dx$ where $u(x)=\begin{cases}1&,x\ge 0\\\\0&,x<0\end{cases}$

Comment: In $(1)$  hold when $k=0$ ?

Comment: See the comments on 26 February 2018.

Comment: There is a typo in the last formula, the rhs should be $(f''(k) -2 s f'(k) + s^2 f(k)) e^{-s k}$.

Comment: @Maxim Indeed.  I've edited accordingly.  Much appreciated.

Comment: There's still a typo in the $f'(k)$ term though.

Comment: @Maxim Ah, yes.  Corrected.  Thank you again.